# Writing a bidirectional iterator for a class

Tags: c++

I have a class that holds strings. Basically the class is built on an array of strings:

```
class stringlist {
public:
    typedef std::string str;
    void push(str);
    void pop();
    void print();
    void resize(size_t);
    size_t capacity();
    size_t size();
    stringlist() : N(15) {}
    stringlist(size_t sz) : N(sz) {}
    ~stringlist() { delete [] container; }
}
private:
    size_t N;
    str* container = new str[N];
};
```

The next part of the exercise asks readers to

*Write a bidirectional iterator for your class*

At this point in the book, there is no talk of overloaded operators etc.

If I have something like `str* iterator(*str)`, how would I manage incrementation, decrementation, etc. I am assuming I can write a separate function for these methods but that seems like it would defeat the purpose of writing a `iterator` data member in the first place. Would the iterator be a separate class?

Also, would it be possible to have the increment decrement functions inside the iterator so that I can dot into the iterator to use these functions?

Comment: This is aside from the question but your class will have horrible problems if you ever copy or reassign it since you haven't implemented those operators. *Seriously* consider using a `vector` instead of `new`.

Comment: @MarkB. Yes. It's a work in progress.

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: @JohnDibling. Accelerated C++. Exercise 10-5.

Comment: That surprises me.  ACPP is an excellent book, highly recommended by SO.  The answers to your question are surely addressed there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pointer is a valid bidirectional iterator.  (It is also random-access)

So you can add iterator support to your class with

```
typedef str* iterator;
typedef const str* const_iterator;
iterator begin() { return container; }
const_iterator begin() const { return container; }
iterator end() { return begin() + size(); }
const_iterator end() const { return begin() + size(); }
const_iterator cbegin() const { return begin(); }
const_iterator cend() const { return end(); }
```

However, you can't use pointers to implement reverse iteration (which uses `++` to go backwards, and `--` to go forwards).  But the Standard library provides [a nice adaptor (in `#include <iterator>`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

```
typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
reverse_iterator rbegin() { return reverse_iterator(end()); }
reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator(begin()); }
const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator(end()); }
const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return const_reverse_iterator(begin()); }
const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return rbegin(); }
const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return rend(); }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is standard in C++11, so you can say `auto it = v.cbegin();` and be sure to get a `const_iterator`.

Comment: Using this method, if I wanted to increment would I do something like `iterator inc() { return container + 1; }`?

Comment: @Dochevsky: `++` and `--` work on pointers, so you can do the usual `for( auto it = SL.begin(), end = SL.end(); it != end; ++it )`.  C++11 range-based for will also work.  `for( auto elem : SL )`

Comment: Also, shouldn't I make a new pointer to container and return that pointer instead of returning container since then the position in the container will move inherently?

Comment: @Dochevsky: `return container;` in a return-by-value function makes a copy of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator is usually implemented as a nested class of the class you iterate. You overload the increment and decrement operators of the nested class. It may make sense now why you write `vector<int>::iterator it` - `iterator` is in fact a class nested within `vector<int>`.